# How can I add a new column to dataframe that uses a function to check if values from two columns fit specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates, trigonometry

I have a dataframe similar to the below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1.01,-2.02,None], 'col_2': [1.01,-2.02,None]}, columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
```

You can think of col_1 and col_2 as x- and y-coordinates, respectively. I need to be able to check each row of this dataframe against three triangles on a coordinate plane and add a column 'col_3' to the dataframe that tells me which of the three triangles the point lies within.

For example, at index 0 we see the point (1.01, 1.01). If I have

'triangle 1' with the points `(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.1), (3.2, 0.0)`,

'triangle 2' with the points `(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -3.1), (-3.1, 0.0)`, and

'triangle 3' with the points `(3.5, 0.0), (3.5, 3.5), (4.5, 0.0)`,

then the point at index 0 `(1.01, 1.01)` will lie within 'triangle 1' and col_3 for index 0 will have the value 'triangle 1'. The row for index 1 `(-2.02, -2.02)` will land within 'triangle 2' and index 2 will be None, or null, since there are no points there.

I found a set of functions that work well to determine whether a point lies within the triangle, I am just not sure how to tie everything together:

```
# A utility function to calculate area of triangle formed by (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3)
def area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)

# A function to check whether point P(x, y) lies inside the triangle formed by A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2) and C(x3, y3)
def isInside(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y):
    # Calculate area of triangle ABC
    A = area (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    # Calculate area of triangle PBC
    A1 = area (x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    # Calculate area of triangle PAC
    A2 = area (x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3)
    # Calculate area of triangle PAB
    A3 = area (x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y)

    # Check if sum of A1, A2 and A3 is same as A
    if(A == A1 + A2 + A3):
        return True
    else:
        return False
# Driver program to test above function
# Let us check whether the point P(10, 15) lies inside the triangle formed by A(0, 0), B(20, 0) and C(10, 30) 
if (isInside(0, 0, 20, 0, 10, 30, 10, 15)):
    print('Inside')
else:
    print('Not Inside')
```

In the `isInside` function above, the first 6 arguments are different for each triangle, and the last 2 arguments should be the `col_1` and `col_2` values for each row. I tried some “if” conditional mess but ended up with

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' and ValueError("The truth
>   value of a {0} is ambiguous.").

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def whereIsIt(row):
    x = row['col_1']
    y = row['col_2']
    if x is None or y is None:
        return None
    #(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.1), (3.2, 0.0)
    if isInside(0.0,0.0,0.0,2.1,3.2,0.0,x,y):
        return 1
    # (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -3.1), (-3.1, 0.0)
    elif isInside(0.0,0.0,0.0,-3.1,-3.1,0.0,x,y):
        return 2
    #(3.5, 0.0), (3.5, 3.5), (4.5, 0.0)
    elif isInside(3.5,0.0,3.5,3.5,4.5,0.0,x,y):
        return 3
    else:
        return None

df['col_3']=df.apply(lambda row: whereIsIt(row),axis=1)
df.head()
```

BTW, the output is:

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   1.01    1.01    1.0
1   -2.02   -2.02   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN
```

(-2.02, -2.02) is not inside  'triangle 2' with the points (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -3.1), (-3.1, 0.0), or the function your provided is wrong. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! You’re right, that point is outside triangle 2. I blame the festivities.. Happy New Year!